# Take screenshot of a selected frame in a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, screenshot

How to take screenshot of a selected frame in UIView and set it as a UIImage?

I Also tried this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width,height));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[imageview.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Change your context to be the context of the UIView you want to capture.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702834/programmatically-take-a-screenshot-of-specific-area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
CGRect rect = [captureView bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[captureView.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```