# How to capture camera only visible view in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I have created a view controller and 50% of the view is camera view other 50% are buttons etc.
The problem that I am facing is when I capture image much larger image is captured and I want to capture only what I can see in that 50% of the view.
So it looks something like this:
This is what I see in view:
[image]
And this is what I get as image after capture:
[image]
Code behind this is:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.view.layer;
    NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    [captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.view.bounds;
    [self.vImagePreview.view.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
    NSLog(@"Rect of self.view: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.vImagePreview.view.frame));
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load camera
    vImagePreview = [[CameraViewController alloc]init];

    vImagePreview.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 500);
    [self.view addSubview:vImagePreview.view];

    vImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    vImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300);

    [self.view addSubview:vImage];

}
```

And this is event when I try to capture image:

```
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
            {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) { break; }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
         if (exifAttachments)
         {
             // Do something with the attachments.
             NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
         }
         else
             NSLog(@"no attachments");

         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
         image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

         UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
         successAlert.title = @"Review Picture";
         successAlert.message = @"";
         [successAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Save"];
         [successAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Retake"];

         [successAlert setDelegate:self];

         UIImageView *_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 40, 40)];
         _imageView.image = image;
         [successAlert addSubview:_imageView];
         [successAlert show];

         UIImage *_image = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(640,480) :_imageView.image];
         NSData *idata = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image)];
         encodedImage = [self encodeBase64WithData:idata];
     }];
```

Why I am getting whole camera view how I can shrink size of what camera capture so I can capture only what is seen in camera view?

Comment: You can also try taking screenshot for a given rect directly, that will reduce your work to scale and other thing.. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15304222/790842

Answer (score 1):

You can crop your image after capture. Try this

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);
// or use the UIImage wherever you like
[UIImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Or try this

```
- (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)rect {
if (self.scale > 1.0f) {
    rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * self.scale,
                      rect.origin.y * self.scale,
                      rect.size.width * self.scale,
                      rect.size.height * self.scale);
}

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, rect);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
return result;
}
```

Refer this link also : [Crop UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage)

Comment: But how I can know origin x and y?

Comment: For this you need to give the rect by trial and error method by giving frame manually by running the code. My suggestion is you can try taking the screenshot of the captured image and then calculate the difference of origin.x from the required image. Once you get the rect this will make next all captures perfect.

Comment: This is a terrible advice, its not trial an error, the image itself has a width and height property, the view has it as well, the preview view has it to. You can compute what would be the actual visible frame based on those properties.